# Update: How do i add additional group or user asigned managed identity and use users/groups names instead of UUIDs?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, terraform-template-file

Main.tf

```
provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    locals {
      access_map = {
        owner_other_access = {
          permissions_access = "---"
          type               = "other"
        },
        owner_group_access = {
          permissions_access = "r-x"
          type               = "group"
        },
        owner_mask_access = {
          permissions_access = "rwx"
          type               = "mask"
        },
        owner_user_access = {
          permissions_access = "rwx"
          type               = "user"
        }
      }
    
      default_map = {
        owner_other_default = {
          permissions_default = "---"
          type                = "other"
        },
        owner_group_default = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "group"
        },
        owner_mask_default = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "mask"
        },
        owner_user_default = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "user"
        }
      }
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "this" {
      for_each = var.storage_containers
    
      name               = each.value.sc_name
      storage_account_id = each.value.storage_account_id
    
      properties = {}
    
      dynamic "ace" {
        for_each = merge(local.access_map, jsondecode(each.value.acl_access))
        iterator = item
    
        content {
          type        = item.value.type
          scope       = "access"
          permissions = item.value.permissions_access
          id          = lookup(item.value, "id", null)
        }
      }
    
      dynamic "ace" {
        for_each = merge(local.default_map, jsondecode(each.value.acl_default))
        iterator = item
    
        content {
          type        = item.value.type
          scope       = "default"
          permissions = item.value.permissions_default
          id          = lookup(item.value, "id", null)
        }
      }
    }
```

teraform.tfvars

```
storage_containers_fs = {
  raw_fs_container = {
    storage_account_id = "bronze_storage_account"
    sc_name            = "rawfs"
    acl_access         = "{\"owner_group_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"r-x\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"3f97daxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":\"f5509xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\"}}"
    acl_default        = "{\"owner_group_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"3f97daxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":\"f5509xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\"}}"
  }
}
```

varaibles.tf

```
variable "storage_containers_fs" {
  description = "Storage Containers settings"
  type = map(object({
    storage_account_id = string
    sc_name            = string
    acl_access         = string
    acl_default        = string
  }))
}
```

My problem with this code is: When deploying for the very first time, this code works and creates a private container with `ACL` inside, assigning the correct rights to the two identities, in this case two groups, as seen above

When deploying this code again with a new group added to thte existing ones, the code fails by trying to replace the first group in the list with the new one added.

The new `tfvars` will look like this:

```
storage_containers_fs = {
  raw_fs_container = {
    storage_account_id = "bronze_storage_account"
    sc_name            = "rawfs"
    acl_access         = "{\"owner_group_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"r-x\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"3f97daxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":\"f5509xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":\"deb25xxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\"}}"
    acl_default        = "{\"owner_group_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"3f97daxxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\",\"id\":\"f5509xxxx-xxxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx\"}}"
  }
}
```

This is the output from `apply`:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.az_bronze_storage_containers_fs.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.this["raw_fs_container"] will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "this" {
        id                 = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/rawfs"
        name               = "rawfs"
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

      - ace {
          - permissions = "---" -> null
          - scope       = "access" -> null
          - type        = "other" -> null
        }
      - ace {
          - permissions = "---" -> null
          - scope       = "default" -> null
          - type        = "other" -> null
        }
      - ace {
          - permissions = "rwx" -> null
          - scope       = "access" -> null
          - type        = "mask" -> null
        }
      - ace {
          - permissions = "rwx" -> null
          - scope       = "access" -> null
          - type        = "user" -> null
        }
      - ace {
          - permissions = "rwx" -> null
          - scope       = "default" -> null
          - type        = "mask" -> null
        }
      - ace {
          - permissions = "rwx" -> null
          - scope       = "default" -> null
          - type        = "user" -> null
        }
      - ace {
          - id          = "3f97xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx" -> null
          - permissions = "r-x" -> null
          - scope       = "access" -> null
          - type        = "group" -> null
        }
      + ace {
          + id          = "deb25xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"
          + permissions = "r-x"
          + scope       = "access"
          + type        = "group"
        }
      + ace {
          + permissions = "---"
          + scope       = "access"
          + type        = "other"
        }
      + ace {
          + permissions = "---"
          + scope       = "default"
          + type        = "other"
        }
      + ace {
          + permissions = "rwx"
          + scope       = "access"
          + type        = "mask"
        }
      + ace {
          + permissions = "rwx"
          + scope       = "access"
          + type        = "user"
        }
      + ace {
          + permissions = "rwx"
          + scope       = "default"
          + type        = "mask"
        }
      + ace {
          + permissions = "rwx"
          + scope       = "default"
          + type        = "user"
        }

        # (1 unchanged block hidden)
    }

Plan: 0 to add, 1 to change, 0 to destroy.
module.az_bronze_storage_containers_fs.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.this["raw_fs_container"]: Modifying... [id=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/rawfs]
╷
│ Error: setting access control for root path in File System "rawfs" in Storage Account "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx": datalakestore.Client#SetAccessControl: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="AuthorizationPermissionMismatch" Message="This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:e59de7e1-b01f-0066-41cd-3f5884000000\nTime:2024-01-05T11:48:36.0364932Z"
│
│   with module.az_bronze_storage_containers_fs.azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem.this["raw_fs_container"],
│   on ..\templates\az-storage-filesystem\main.tf line 42, in resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "this":
│   42: resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "this" {
```

Not sure why this doesn't work.

Ideally is to add a new group without removing the existing one (first problem) **AND** can we make this template use group names instead of `UUIDs` in the `tfvars` (second problem)? Maybe using `data.azuread_users`, `data.azuread_groups`, `data.azuread_serviceprincipals`? Hardcoding IDs in the tfvars doesn't seem like a good idea. I would personally add the group name instead of the ID and let the template resolve the ID for me.

I was expecting a new identity to be added instead of replacing an existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ideally is to add a new group without removing the existing one (first problem).

To modify the existing container , you may need **Storage Blob Data Owner** role. Follow the [Ms doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control-model#role-based-access-control-azure-rbac) for more details

[image]

> can we make this template use group names instead of `UUIDs` in the`tfvars` (second problem)? Maybe using `data.azuread_users`, `data.azuread_groups`, `data.azuread_serviceprincipals`? Hardcoding IDs in the tfvars doesn't seem like a good idea.

If you create containers using .tfvars, it accepts an **ID**, not a name. However, you can use the code below to create a container without hardcoding the **group ID** by using a `data block`

**terraform.tfvars**

```
storage_containers = {
  container1 = {
    storage_account_id = ""
    sc_name            = "container1"
    acl_access         = "{\"owner_user_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"r-x\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"data.azuread_group.example.id\"},\"owner_other_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
    acl_default        = "{\"owner_user_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"data.azuread_group.example.id\"},\"owner_other_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
  },
  container2 = {
    storage_account_id = ""
    sc_name            = "container2"
    acl_access         = "{\"owner_user_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"r-x\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"Group-ID\"},\"owner_other_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_access\":{\"permissions_access\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
    acl_default        = "{\"owner_user_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"user\"},\"owner_group_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"group\",\"id\":\"Group-ID\"},\"owner_other_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"---\",\"type\":\"other\"},\"owner_mask_default\":{\"permissions_default\":\"rwx\",\"type\":\"mask\"}}"
  }
}
```

Here is the updated code to create an containers without .tfvars file.

```kotlin
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    locals {
      access_map = {
        container1 = {
          permissions_access = "rwx"
          type               = "group"
        },
        container2 = {
          permissions_access = "rwx"
          type               = "user"
        }
      }
    
      default_map = {
        group = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "group"
        },
        user = {
          permissions_default = "rwx"
          type                = "user"
        },
      }
    }
    
    data "azuread_group" "example" {
      display_name = "Azure-AD-Group-Name"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
      name                = "storage-account-name"
      resource_group_name = "RG-name"
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_storage_data_lake_gen2_filesystem" "example" {
      for_each = local.access_map
    
      name               = each.key
      storage_account_id = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.id
    
      dynamic "ace" {
        for_each = [data.azuread_group.example.id]
    
        content {
          id          = ace.value
          permissions = local.access_map[each.key].permissions_access
          scope       = "access"
          type        = local.access_map[each.key].type
        }
      }
    
      dynamic "ace" {
        for_each = local.default_map
    
        content {
          type        = ace.key
          scope       = "default"
          permissions = ace.value.permissions_default
          id          = data.azuread_group.example.id
        }
      }
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]